# Alternative to Generics, to allow storing objects of same class but with different property type in EF

Tags: .net, entity-framework, sqlite, database-design, ef-code-first

So, I have a system which logs different types of values from different devices. Each device may provide multiple values that should be logged.

I need to describe each device, a description of each sensor connected to a device, a description of the different types of values the sensor provides (such as Pressure and Temperature for a Depth-sensor), and finally a collection of logged values for each of these again. What I have tried so far is akin to this:

```
// The device which the sensor is connected to
public class Device
{
    public int DeviceId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

// A sensor that is connected to a Device. 
public class Sensor
{
    public int SensorId { get; set; }
    public int DeviceId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } // for example "Depth"
    public ICollection<SensorValueDescription> ValueDescriptions { get; set; }
}

// A description of a single value provided by a sensor (Such as "Degrees Celcius")
public class SensorValueDescription
{
    public int SensorId { get; set;}
    public int SensorValueDescriptionId { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; } // for example "Bar or Degrees Celcius"
    public ICollection<SensorValue> SensorValues { get; set; }
}

// A single measurement
public class SensorValue 
{
    public int SensorValueDescriptionId { get; set; }
    public int SensorValueId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; } // <-- This is the problem
}
```

This works fine in .net. I can set any type of value in `SensorValue.Value`, and later read the type and do something with this.

However, trying to use this code with Entity Framework, no column gets created for this property.

When creating and saving new Devices with Sensors, SensorValueDescriptions and SensorValues to the database in one DbContext, and reading them back in another, everything looks fine except for that `SensorValueDescription.SensorValues` is always null.

I tried to make a solution using Generics instead of using the `object`-property, but I didn't get that to work either.

Then I started to think how I would actually try to model something like this in the database, and fell a bit short.

I thought about having different "Value-tables" for each different value type: FloatValues, DoubleValues, StringValues, IntegerValues etc., which has one column for timestamp and one for value. But this would create many different tables, and I would somehow need to join on different table names based on the type of value.

Then I started thinking about modelling it like a sparse table, where I have a column for each value type, but only the column with the correct type gets populated for a given row. However, this seems like it would be painful to use in my .net code.

To make matters worse, some sensors can return a sample which is an array of any of the supported types.

What would be a good solution for something like this? In theory, the task at hand seems quite simple, yet I am having trouble finding a good solution.

Comment: unrelated but your sensor table probably needs a DeviceId or device needs to hold a list of sensors as from what i can see there is no link between the two.

Comment: Corrected that now. The code above is a simplification of what I am actually working with, with many fields removed. Guess I removed too much :)